# how to get background image in email using nodemailer

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, nodemailer

so the images are displaying in the email but i want to use it as a background image for a particular section?
i tried using background-img: url('background.png') but this didn't work
any idea how to get background images using nodemailer?

```
let mailOptions = {
                    from: process.env.SYSTEM_EMAIL_USER,
                    to: to,
                    bcc: bcc,
                    subject: " Verify your account",
                    text: `The content of thi email requires html`,
                    headers: { "x-vendor-partner": "gensler" },

                    html: `<div style='max-width: 600px;'>
                          <div style='text-align: center;'>
                              <img src="cid:fprobanner" alt="FPro Banner" width="320" />
                          </div>
                           
                        <br>
                        <div style="font-size:19px;
                                    font-family: Calibri, Futura;">
                        <h1 style="
                        width: 100vw;
                        color: white;
                        text-align: center;
                        background-color: #0099FF;
                        "> Welcome! </h1>
                        
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                          Dear ${user.firstname ? user.firstname : "user"},
                            <br>
                            <br>

                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            Please verify your account by clicking the link
                                 <a href='${verify_link}' target='_blank'>HERE:</a>
                                 <br>
                                 <br>
                                 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                 You will be redirected to create your account password.
                                 <br>
                                 <br>
                              <div>
                              <img style="border: 1px solid #cee3ed" src="cid:background" alt="FPro Banner" width="10px">
                              </div> 
                        </div>        
                        </div>
                        `,
                 
                    attachments: [{
                            filename: "updated_logo.png",
                            path: (path.join(__dirname, '/images/updated_logo.png')),
                            cid: "fprobanner",
                        },
                        {
                            filename: "background.jpg",
                            path: (path.join(__dirname, '/images/background.jpg')),
                            cid: "background",
                        },
                    ],
                };
```

Comment: have you already found a solution i am currently experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the CSS like in this example:

[How To Create a Full Height Image](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_full_page.asp)

I don't know if it will be possible, I found this in

[Nodemailer Docs](https://community.nodemailer.com/using-embedded-images/)

- Using Embedded Images

  Attachments can be used as embedded images in the HTML body.

Comment: in your example above it shows background-image: url("img.jpg"); which is not working, i tried it already.